# Classic Asp issue in IIS8.5 Windows2012 Server

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I've moved my classic asp app to win 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5). This app uses COM component. I've registered this component using regsvr32 and also exported older components from II 6 to II 8.5. I can see those components in control pane->component services.

This app is not working properly. Code include Server.CreateObject("myCOM"); looks like it works but when I try to get objArgs["prop1"]; it doesn't work. I see this error "Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is denied to this object." What could be potential issue?

Comment: Try creating the object using a WSH script on the server using the 32 and 64-bit versions of `wscript.exe` to rule out issues with component registration.

Comment: If it's a 32-bit component, do you have "enable 32 bit applications" set to True for the default or custom application pool?

Comment: To register the COM component you have to use regasm rather than regsvr32.  Also make sure the the IUSR account has permissions to the folder in which the DLLs are